# How to resize AlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using alertView and trying to resize it's frame with

```
UIalertView *alert = [UIAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,300,400)];
[alert setTitle:"Alert View"];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

but, it's showing the exaxt frame as before. I am new in iphone dev. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

the alertview is not designed to have a custom size. it determines its size by itself which depends on the tile, text and buttons.

why do you want to resize it?
iOS 5 features some alertview with inputfields. maybe this is useful for you.

```
alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
```